# How to properly serve progressive jpeg from nginx?

Tags: linux, nginx, web-server, configuration

I have a progressive jpeg that I am trying to use in my test website (localhost). But it does not seem to show the low res to high res image. The image just pops up, even when the bandwidth is throttled. From the test I have conducted it appears that the issue lies on my nginx server, not sure if its the config or the server itself.

But I seems to not believe that my deductions are correct that the server is to blame.

Here are the test that I have done that yields negative results

- encode images using php-gd or imagick with interlaced enabled
- firefox vs chrome
- used a known progressive image http://www.reasoft.com/tutorials/web/img/progress.jpg (things work on that server from my chrome but not from my server)
- change nginx 1.14 to 1.16.1
- Cleared cache via devtool
- enabled image_filter_interlace on;

Here is my nginx config file:

```
worker_processes 32;
worker_rlimit_nofile 524288;
events
{
    use epoll;
    worker_connections  100000;
    multi_accept on;
}

http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;
    open_file_cache max=100000;
    keepalive_requests 100000;
    keepalive_timeout 30;
    index index.php;
    server {
        listen 127.0.0.1:443 ssl http2;
        server_name    static.example.com;
        root "/static/root";
        ssl_certificate "/static/server/cert.cer";
        ssl_certificate_key "/static/server/key.key";
        ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:1m;
        ssl_session_timeout 5m;
        ssl_ciphers HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
        fastcgi_hide_header Set-Cookie;
        location ~* \.(?:png|jpeg|jpg)$ {
            expires 30d;
            add_header Pragma public;
            add_header Cache-Control "public";
            add_header Accept-Ranges bytes;
        }
    }
}
```

SYSTEM: CentOS 8.1 PHP 7

Did I miss anything?

**Edit:**

I updated the config to include image filter module, but same negative results:

```
worker_processes 32;
worker_rlimit_nofile 524288;
load_module /location/of/ngx_http_image_filter_module.so;
...
http {
    ...
    server {
        ...
        location ~* \.(?:png|jpeg|jpg)$ {
            image_filter resize 1000 1000;
            image_filter_interlace on;
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Havw you cleared browse cache before throttling?

Comment: Yes, I always have it cleared whenever I am in chrome dev tool

Comment: Have you checked the image filter module?.. http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_image_filter_module.html. Specifically set 'image_filter_interlace on' Also take a look at https://www.endpoint.com/blog/2016/05/25/caching-resizing-reverse-proxying-image-server-nginx.

Comment: I have read the documentation, but it says, its for modifying images just-in-time, my images area already progressive and I just want that the server serve it in a progressive manner. Anyway, I tried it, but same negative result.